# How to create a top margin after an auto page break with css?

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation

Here is the description of the feature I really struggle to do.

**Mockup**

[image: How to add a top margin page 3?]

**Description**

- A generated pdf document contains many sections
- Some sections can print on many pages
- We don't know the size of the content (variable height)
- The page must not have margins (the headers are positioned (0,0) and have the same width as the page, documents are printed bordeless)
- The content can be anything : paragraphs, titles, images, graphs, svg elements, tables, ...

**Objective**

When the content of a section auto break on the next page, that page should have a margin equal to the header

Exemple: the section #2 is printed on the pages 2 & 3 ; the page 3 should have a top margin.

**Problem**

Because the page margins are set to "0", we should define a padding/margin after a natural page break but, I can't find how to make it work nicely (1)

**Technical**

I'm using [RelaxedJS](https://github.com/RelaxedJS/ReLaXed/issues/144) (pdf is generated with Chromium)

Thank you so much in advance if you know how to handle that specific case. I've read so many documentation. The best candidate could be [CSS Fragmentation Box Decoration Break Clone](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#valdef-box-decoration-break-clone) but I can't make it work with blocks, only inline elements and paragraphs.

---

(1) I have tried a solution using table and a thead setting the margin on top of the page... but it's not working when you fill the cells with content. I guess the  has serious limitations when using @page rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had to face the same issue a few days ago.

The **idea** was simple, you have to do this:

- Set `@page` margins (considering the `height` of the `header` and `footer`)
- Set `header` and `footer` `position: fixed` and adjust the `top` and `bottom` properties.
- Control the `.page-content` with `page-break-after` to make sure the content go to the next pages.

> **Notice** that I used the [DOMPDF Laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to generate the PDF.  May be there are some differences using [RelaxedJS](https://github.com/RelaxedJS/ReLaXed) but anyway you can try this just in case.

I hope this can help you. *[Here is the same code in Codepen](https://codepen.io/aruizh/pen/eYmBbNK)*

```css
@page { 
  margin: 160px 0px;   
  padding: 0;     
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

header { 
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  position: fixed; 
  top: -120px; 
  left: 0px; 
  right: 0px;   
}

.page-content {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.page-content p {
    page-break-after: always; 
    padding: 5px 30px;
  
}

.page-content p:last-child { 
    page-break-after: never; 
}

footer { 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 50px; 
    right: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 50px;
  
}

footer, .page-content {
  margin-left: 100px;
  border-left: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<header><h2>HEADER SECTION #</h2></header>
<div class="page-content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque neque vel lectus rutrum, quis suscipit tortor ornare. Maecenas a enim sit amet neque vehicula imperdiet. Donec auctor convallis tellus. Suspendisse a arcu a tortor congue aliquet vel a justo. Cras sit amet pulvinar tortor. Vestibulum vel lobortis libero, eu accumsan ipsum. Donec felis sem, consequat quis pharetra sit amet, facilisis eget odio. Suspendisse nec vestibulum urna, non fermentum lorem.</p>
  <p>Sed orci neque, fringilla nec urna at, iaculis laoreet metus. Nam fringilla sit amet sapien iaculis malesuada. Duis pellentesque odio vitae quam pellentesque sollicitudin. Duis nec commodo mauris, ac eleifend nunc. Vestibulum ac finibus nisi. Aliquam at neque augue. Cras metus mi, ultricies vitae dui sit amet, lacinia aliquet nunc. Duis vitae urna et arcu auctor tristique et id lectus. Praesent ut sollicitudin nibh. Mauris quis vehicula ipsum. Quisque feugiat nec felis et cursus. Donec neque ante, accumsan a tincidunt at, ultrices et lectus. Nullam finibus, ipsum facilisis euismod accumsan, nulla quam ultrices odio, id efficitur purus nisl id lacus. Duis bibendum est quis ligula aliquam rhoncus. Nunc dapibus, odio vel tincidunt faucibus, justo dolor tempor nisl, eu maximus nibh odio nec risus. Nullam ut lacinia purus.</p>
  <p>Praesent finibus nisi congue sodales elementum. Vestibulum mauris libero, varius a urna at, vestibulum eleifend nisl. Maecenas et metus dapibus, semper quam a, suscipit libero. Mauris malesuada pretium maximus. Sed semper urna vitae iaculis mattis. Praesent luctus, ipsum et consequat lacinia, purus nisi scelerisque sem, eu luctus metus erat at arcu. Aenean aliquam fermentum condimentum.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque felis mi, semper ac ullamcorper vel, accumsan ac tortor. Donec vestibulum varius enim, vitae tempor ligula accumsan eget. Etiam quis nunc felis. Phasellus scelerisque, purus eget sollicitudin gravida, felis justo euismod dui, ut fringilla nulla nunc vitae risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam commodo pretium sapien eleifend molestie. Nullam consequat ligula sit amet purus sodales vehicula. Duis placerat aliquet augue, ut dapibus turpis malesuada sit amet. Vivamus id nulla odio. Integer a velit ac eros rutrum tempus. Vestibulum quis sodales turpis.</p>
  <p>Vivamus eu enim fringilla turpis euismod finibus id quis dolor. Pellentesque ex massa, congue at nisl at, lacinia ornare urna. Aenean pretium posuere dictum. Nullam justo metus, eleifend a dictum sit amet, gravida ut arcu. Fusce libero leo, sollicitudin at est non, venenatis auctor nulla. Vivamus luctus tellus eu metus interdum congue eget non magna. Curabitur congue felis nulla, eu consectetur tellus viverra et. Nunc ullamcorper ac nisl a elementum. Morbi viverra magna in orci tristique, eget suscipit nunc suscipit. Morbi sodales dolor a feugiat bibendum. Duis nunc nisl, pulvinar at sem quis, cursus lacinia arcu. Aliquam in dictum arcu.</p>
</div>
<footer>Page X</footer>
```